# How to get the name of a regex named capturing group?

Tags: python, regex, text, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a regex in Python like :`(?P<HEADER>\S+)` and I want to get the name of the capturing group (`"HEADER"`) and also the value of its match.

I have many  different headers so it must be generic and in code.

For example, if I have `(?P<key1>[regex1])` and `(?P<key2>[regex2])` I would want to programatically get `key1` and `key2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all the details of the match (including the names of the groups themselves):

```
>>> match = re.match("(?P<letter>A)", "A")
>>> match.groupdict()
{'letter': 'A'}
```

Comment: i am asking if there is an option to get the named capturing group?

Comment: Yes, and don't my code samples answer that question? These are two ways to get the contents of a named capturing group...

Comment: it does not samples . i want the named capturing group and not it's content. i want to get for example from regex pattren the word 'letter' and by this i will get the content.

Comment: @OshikawaL In that case use the match's `groupdict()` method.

Comment: @OshikawaL: See my edit. Oh, Duncan also noticed that. But why don't you know the names of the groups in a regex you just performed?